# Does asymmetric fraction of finite groups tend to $0$?

Tags: probability, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, automorphism-group

Let’s define asymmetric fraction of a finite group $G$ as the number $af(G) = \frac{|\{(g, a) \in G \times Aut(G)| a(g) = g\}|}{|G||Aut(G)|}$. Equivalently it can be defined as $P(A(X) = X)$, where $A$ and $X$ are independent uniformly distributed random elements of $Aut(G)$ and $G$ respectively.

Is it true, that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall G ((\lvert\,G\,\rvert > n) \to (af(G) < \epsilon))$?

I know, that $af(C_{p^n}) = \dfrac{p^n + \Sigma_{i = 1}^n  p^ip^{n - 1 - i}(p - 1)}{p^{2n - 1}(p - 1)} = \dfrac{(np - n + 1)}{p^n(p - 1)}$ and, that $af(G) \leq \frac{1}{2} + \dfrac{|\{g \in G| \forall a \in Aut(G) \text{ } a(g) = g\}|}{2|G|}$. However this is clearly not enough to prove the statement.

Comment: Do you mean $< \epsilon$ rather than $ < G$?

Comment: Since there are only finitely many finite groups of a given order, the conjecture can be stated more plainly as "all but finitely many finite groups have asymmetric fraction less than any given positive real," or equivalently as "$0$ is the only limit point of the set of asymmetric fractions of finite groups."

Comment: If we replace ${\rm Aut}(G)$ with ${\rm Inn}(G)$, this is the commuting probability, which famously must be $\le 5/8$ if it is not $1$. IIRC the set of commuting probabilities of finite groups (maybe conjecturally) has order type the reverse of the ordinal $\omega^{\omega}$.

Comment: This isn't quite the commuting probability, even for $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, unless the group is also centerless, since the commuting probability counts every element of the group, whereas this concept doesn't distinguish between elements that correspond to the same inner automorphism.

Comment: @runway44 Either $\omega^\omega$, or $\omega^{\omega^2}$, not sure which!

Comment: Its' true for finite abelian groups.  This was [proved](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1975.11993813) by Gary Sherman.